# Webkit in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, mono, webkit, monodevelop

I'm using Mono 2.10 and MonoDevelop 2.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm new in Mono. I created a simple application using this [tutorial](http://shana.worldofcoding.com/en/browser.html). And now i have 2 questions:

1 - **Referencing webkit-sharp.dll**. I can find this dll in my system under the path `usr\lib\mono\gac\webkit-sharp\1.1.15.0__eaa1d335d2e19745\webkit-sharp.dll`,
but it is not visible for MonoDevelop. I can add it only by specifying the full path to dll.
This situation seems not normal to me. Probably i should install some more packages to make webkit-sharp.dll visible or use another dll?

2 - Tutorial creates gtk# application. Is it possible to use webkit in winforms application? If yes, how it can be done? I need to port existing winforms app (with embedded webkit) to Mono. If it is possible to create winform app with webkit on Mono - it will save my time.

Comment: I noticed that you are fairly new here. Feel free to upvote an answer that gives you insight. You can accept an answer as well. Doing this will let people know that you are a good community member, and then other members will be more likely in the future to answer your questions. That way everyone wins! CHEERS!

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer both of your queries:

1) You can add the reference to webkit-sharp.dll by right clicking on "references" in the "solutions" area:

[image]

Then click on "Edit References":

[image: Edit References]

Then select the ".NET Assembly" tab. Navigate to find "webkit-sharp.dll", and your set as far as references go. In your code of course you will need something like:

```
using webkit-sharp
```

2) I wouldn't do that. Not that you can't, but my reasoning here is that MonoDevelop can compile things with winforms, but in terms of designing the GUI stuff, afaik, there is no GUI editor for winforms that works with MonoDevelop. MonoDevelop uses GTK# in the GUI design. (It is not impossible to do what you want, but just not recommended.)

CHEERS!

Comment: Your answer on my first question is not quite what I wanted to hear. But i found a solution. Package `libwebkit-cil-dev` makes `webkit-sharp.dll` visible to monodevelop.

Comment: I answered the questions that you posed. You might want to edit your question to reflect your real issue, you might consider giving people some credit for their answers in the form of upvoting at least. Eventually you will understand how this community works and that people who put some effort into answering questions are rewarded for their efforts. Question posters are rewarded by being more specific with their exact question and rewarding answer posters, otherwise people won't bother answering. Everyone in the community wins that way. We want to make SO an excellent resource. CHEERS!

Comment: @happy coder you answer on the first part of the question is exactly what was described in the question. This way doesn't seem normal to Anton. CHEERS!